# Add custom header in Swagger request for ASP.NET Core 6 using FastEndpoints

Tags: c#, swagger, .net-6.0, fast-endpoints

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerDoc(settings =>
{
    settings.Title = "IPR Backend API";
    settings.Version = "v1";
    settings.AddAuth("ApiKeyAuth", new()
    {
        Name = "ApiKey",
        In = NSwag.OpenApiSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header,
        Type = NSwag.OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
    });
}, addJWTBearerAuth: false);

app.UseOpenApi();
app.UseSwaggerUi3(s => s.ConfigureDefaults());
```

The request contains two headers `ApiKey` and `CorrelationId` which contain some values to be validated before the controller reaches the actual route through the pre processors of fastendpoints. I need to add these custom headers in my request through Swagger. Currently I am unable to run the request through Swagger and need Postman to test my APIs:

[image: Swagger Image]

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be using outdated swagger configuration methods. see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dj-nitehawk/4efe5ef70f813aec2c55fff3bbb833c0) for a full example of api-key authentication with swagger.

and as for adding custom header parameters, you need to register a custom operation processor for nswag as shown in [this example](https://gist.github.com/dj-nitehawk/d172140b1f7d576e632a0d15e9682f54).

all of these examples are linked from the [fastendpoints cookbook](https://fast-endpoints.com/docs/the-cookbook#auth).